# Moving canvas left to right - right to left, change color and size

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have to create a moving rectangle from left to right, and from right to left.

I want to change the color of the rectangle (to a random color) after every 20 pixels the rectangle passes. When the rectangle is on right, its size will change to `100px`, and when it is on the left, its size will go back to `50px`.

For now I have:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    x = 0,
    last = performance.now();
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
function draw(timestamp) {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, 50, 50, 50);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.fill();

  x += (timestamp - last) / 10;
  last = timestamp;
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Comment: do you want 2 rectangles or one which bounces from right to left and then left to right?

Comment: @NickParsons one which bounces from right to left and then left to right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a few things. Firstly, you need to create variables for each thing which has the potential to change. This includes the `size` of the box, the `color` of the box, and the `dir`ection of the box:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  x = 0,
  size = 50,
  dir = 1,
  boxColor = "#ffffff",
  last = performance.now();
```

The variable `dir` is `1`, which means it will take your box's current direction and times it by `1`. If you want to change the direction of your box, we need to subtract from `x`. This means we need to change `dir` to `-1` each time the box hits the right wall, and change it back to `1` when the box hits the left wall. 
To accomplish this, we can add a helper function called `bounce` which checks if the box's width + its size is passed the width of the canvas. If it is, we know the box has gone past the right-hand side of the canvas container. Thus, we can change the boxes direction to `-1`. We can also reposition the box's location to be outside of the wall in case it managed to clip into the wall while moving. We can apply the same logic for checking if the box surpasses the left edge of the canvas. During this checking we can also change the `size` of our box such that it grows when it hits the right wall, and shrinks when it hits the left wall:

```
function bounce() {
    if(x+size > canvas.width) { // if right edge passes the widtth of the canvas, change the dir
    dir *= -1;
    size = 100;;
    x = canvas.width-size; // move the box outside of the wall (boundary)
  } else if(x < 0) {
    dir *= -1;
    size = 50;
    x = 0;
  }
}
```

And thus, we must also change our change in `x` equation to be:

```
x += dir*(timestamp - last) / 10;
```

Lastly, we need to add a way to change the box's colour. This can be done by taking the modulo (`%`) of the `x` position. If `x % 20` equals `0` we know our box is on an `x` position which is a multiple of `20` and so we change its colour. However, as the `x` position doesn't change by `1`'s each time, we need to round `x` before we do this check. Moreover, we need to give this check a bit of leeway as we may skip the `20`<sup>th</sup> pixel and thus won't ever get a multiple of 20, so, we can use `<=1` as our check. (Note: this isn't the perfect check, but it's the best I could come up with for now :/):

```
function color() {
    if(Math.round(x) % 20 <= 1 ) { // if the x divide 20 gives a remainder of 0
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    boxColor = "rgb(" +r +", " +g +", " +b +")";
  } else {
    console.log(Math.round(Math.abs(x)) % 20);
  }
}
```

See example below:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  x = 0,
  size = 50,
  dir = 1,
  boxColor = "#ffffff",
  last = performance.now();
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function draw(timestamp) {
  bounce();
  color();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = boxColor;
  ctx.rect(x, canvas.height / 2 - size / 2, size, size);
  ctx.fill();

  x += dir * (timestamp - last) / 10;
  last = timestamp;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function bounce() {
  if (x + size > canvas.width) { // if right edge passes the widtth of the canvas, change the dir
    dir *= -1;
    size = 100;
    x = canvas.width - size; // move the box outside of the wall (boundary)
  } else if (x < 0) {
    dir *= -1;
    size = 50;
    x = 0;
  }
}

function color() {
  if (Math.round(x) % 20 <= 1) { // if the x divide 20 gives a remainder of 0
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    boxColor = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: black;"></canvas>
```